# getting wrong absolute coordinates android

Tags: android, coordinate-systems

I am trying to get absolute screen coordinates of a button on android. But I am getting them wrong!

I have written my code in a such a way that when my finger goes over the button, it should change its background color to blue. But that's not what's happening. Instead, It changes the background color to blue of the button below it.

Here is my code:

```
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();

int pos[] = new int[2];
button.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
int x1 = pos[0], y1 = pos[1];
int x2 = x1 + button.getWidth();
int y2 = y1 + button.getWidth();

if(x <=x2 && x >= x1  && y <= y2 && y >= y1)
{
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else
{
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget about the density independent pixels: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels
You are not getting the actual pixel location by just using getX() or getY() since you aren't considering the density of you screen.

Comment: So how do I get the actual pixel location?

Comment: @DroidFan He misleads you. You're working with actual pixels. The problem may come from different coordinate systems.

Comment: @AlaksiejN. Thanks. Can you please help me find the soultion?

Comment: @user3126670 It's in Android SDK.

Comment: Yeah my bad, never used that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself. It's quite simple.

Intead of using :

```
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();
```

I used:

```
int x = (int) event.getRawX();
int y = (int) event.getRawY();
```

And the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding getWidth() to both the horizontal and vertical.  Pretty sure u need to use .getHeight() on the y2 line.

```
 int x2 = x1 + button.getWidth();
 int y2 = y1 + button.getWidth();
```

Comment: getHeight instead of?

Comment: Is everyone drunk tonight?  getHeight, instead of getWidth for the vertical.

Comment: use getLeft(), getTop() to get x,y's relative to the parent view.  I believe touch event's x,y's are also relative to the parent view.

Comment: just the same thing in reverse... instead of comparing relative to relative, u'r comparing absolute to absolute now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `event` may pretty much not contain absolute coordinates either. Where does it come from?

Comment: This event is of a Linear layout. In my linear layout, there are two relative layouts. In one of that relative layout, I have this button. Both Relative layouts return false for `ontouchlistener` so this event is handled by my main root linear layout.

Comment: That's all right. But don't forget that your phone also has status bar and stuff like that. Try converting your `event`'s coordinates to screen coordinates and leave the rest of your logic intact.